# subtitle track not showing in html5 video player

Tags: html, css, html5-video

the subtitles from the track element are not visible in html5 video player
can someone help me to fix the problem.
this is my html code

```
<video class="video" autoplay #videoPlayer>
    <source src="../../assets/movies/joker.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <track
        label="English"
        kind="subtitles"
        src="../../assets/Subtitles/jokersubtitles.vtt"
        srclang="en"
    />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the subtitle file in the same folder as the movie